# XSLT for oddly formatted XML File

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an XSLT file to output HTML for the following oddly structured XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_66" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
    <object class="java.util.HashMap">
        <void method="put">
            <string>Field_01</string>
            <long>1005079534</long>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
            <string>Field_02</string>
            <int>1328</int>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
            <string>Field_03</string>
            <string>10050741652</string>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
            <string>properties</string>
            <object class="java.util.Properties">
                <void method="put">
                    <string>Property_01</string>
                    <object class="java.util.HashMap">
                        <void method="put">
                            <string>Attribute_01</string>
                            <array class="java.lang.Object" length="2">
                                <void index="0">
                                    <string>Data_01</string>
                                </void>
                                <void index="1">
                                    <boolean>Data_02</boolean>
                                </void>
                            </array>
                        </void>
                        <void method="put">
                            <string>Attribute_02</string>
                            <array class="java.lang.Object" length="2">
                                <void index="0">
                                    <string>Data_01</string>
                                </void>
                                <void index="1">
                                    <boolean>Data_02</boolean>
                                </void>
                            </array>
                        </void> 
                    </object>
                </void>                     
            </object>
        </void> 
    </object>
</java>
```

I want it formatted to something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Field_01: </h2> <p>1005079534
        <h2>Field_02: </h2> 1328
        <h2>Field_03: </h2> 10050741652
        <h2>Properties</h2>
        <h3>Property_01:</h3>
        <h3>Attribute_01</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Data_01</li>
            <li>Data_02</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Attribute_02</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Data_01</li>
            <li>Data_02</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that XSTL uses the XML tags to create the html file. Is it possible to use XSTL to use the content of the tags in place of tag names to display html instead of name of the tags?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing but XSLT (an XML file itself) can transform other XML into XML, KML, HTML, (i.e., any SGML type) -even text (TXT, CSV, TAB). Also desired output is more the *oddly sturctured* with text values residing outside of any `<div>`,`<span>`, and unclosed `<p>`.

Comment: i understand that XSLT uses the tag name and tag attributes.. but can the XSLT read the text of the tag element instead of the tag name and use that as a template for a html output?

Comment: Define 'oddly formatted'. Either it is XML or it isn't. If it is XML, XSLT can process it. If not, not. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: *can the XSLT read the text of the tag element instead of the tag name* ... still unclear what you are asking or how that relates to your desired result, maybe terminology is getting confused. But yes XSLT can parse any structure of an XML: node values, attribute values, node names, attribute names, namespaces, parents, siblings, child, descendants, ancestors...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use XSLT to use the content of the tags in place of tag names to display html instead of name of the tags?

Yes of course. For example

```
<xsl:element name="{child::string}">
```

constructs an element in the result tree whose name is taken from the content of the child element named "string" in the source tree.